# Use system environment variable for snort.conf HOME_NET setting

Tags: environment-variables, snort

I'm setting up a mass deployment image that includes snort.  Since I don't know the network address range that each image will reside on I thought about using an environment variable to hold the network range and use this environment variable in the `snort.conf` file to set `HOME_NET`.

But that's where everything falls apart.  Can this be done? How?  Essentially, I'm envisioning something like:

```
$ export SYS_HOME_NET=192.168.1.0/16

# snort.conf
ipvar HOME_NET %SYS_HOME_NET%
```

Obviously, this doesn't work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it slightly differently. Assuming the command that gives you the IP range is

```
echo ipvar HOME_NET "$(/sbin/ip route | awk '/eth0/ && ++i==2 { print $1 }')"
```

You could write a little wrapper script that launches `snort`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo ipvar HOME_NET "$(/sbin/ip route | awk '/eth0/ && ++i==2 { print $1 }')" > ~/HOME_NET.conf
snort
```

If you save that file as `snort.sh`, make it executable (`chmod a+x snort.sh`) and run it, it will update the `~/HOME_NET.conf` file with the right IP range *before* launching `snort` so everything should work as you expect it to.

Comment: I like it! I'll probably expand it from being a 1-liner to echoing multiple variables to the conf first then executing snort and specifying which conf to load like this: `/usr/bin/snort -c /path/to/my/snort.conf`

Answer (score 1):

One method I just thought of is to make an external `.conf` file that creates this variable and include it in the `snort.conf` like this:

```
#snort.conf
#ipvar HOME_NET any
include ./HOME_NET.conf
```

Then, create a `HOME_NET.conf` file that looks like this:

```
ipvar HOME_NET 192.168.1.0/16
```

and change/replace the contents of `HOME_NET.conf` with an `.sh` script during boot or initial image setup.